# Why was O. Gabber not an author of the 1983's Faisceaux Pervers?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, representation-theory, sheaf-theory, math-history

Essentially the title. I noticed that in the [2018 re-printed version of *Faisceaux Pervers*](https://smf.emath.fr/publications/faisceaux-pervers), O. Gabber is an author (making the work BBDG) as opposed to the classic *Faisceaux Pervers* (BBD) of 1983 in which the authors are just Beilinson-Bernstein-Deligne.

Comment: Why don't you ask Gabber himself?

Comment: Perhaps better suited to http://hsm.stackexchange.com

Comment: The introduction of the original "Faisceaux pervers" starts with "Il avait d'abord été prévu que O. Gabber soit coauteur du présent article. Il a préféré s'en abstenir pour ne pas être coresponsable des erreurs ou imprécisions qui s'y trouvent". So Gabber was initially supposed to be coauthor but preferred that his name was not mentioned so that is won't be responsible for the mistakes and imprecision of the article.

Comment: I was not an author of that either. Still pisses me off.

Comment: @Roland: That's basically an answer, isn't it?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Yes, maybe. I hesitated because of lhf's comment and because someone may have more informations than what is written here. But I posted this as an answer as suggested.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The introduction of the original "Faisceaux pervers" starts with "Il avait d'abord été prévu que O. Gabber soit coauteur du présent article. Il a préféré s'en abstenir pour ne pas être coresponsable des erreurs ou imprécisions qui s'y trouvent".

So Gabber was initially supposed to be coauthor but preferred that his name was not mentioned so that is won't be responsible for the mistakes and imprecision of the article.